# Is there custom boardgame leaderboard online?

Tags: online, game-accessories

Let me quickly set up a scenario: Me and my cousins all play 7 Wonders. We want to keep track of who is the last person that won and how many wins/losses we each have.

Is there a current online resource (outside of Google sheets) that can allow me to do this?

Comment: I still find this funny that in a site called "Board and Card games" this is off topic lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the iOS app BG Stats (Board Game Stats) for that use (and many others, this app is just awesome). Or you can use Nemestats, an online tool.

Answer (score 9):

If you have an account on [BoardGameGeek](http://www.boardgamegeek.com), then you can record "plays" of a game against that account. You can include details about other players, whether the game was stopped before the end, how long the game took, where the game was played, and who won.

Comment: If you use the [SPLU](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/183412/log-plays-faster-splu) add on. It makes logging players not actually annoying. You can save player names and player BGG names, You can actually get stat fairly quickly and easily.

BGG actually makes a great place to store your gaming records. it's just  not that userfriendly. SPLU helps with that *a lot*. The only problem with BGG recording is that it's account dependent as far as I know. Only ONE person can keep the records. Even if you input someone's username it won't show up in their play records.

Comment: You can however use a group account to resolve this or designate one person as the record keeper. Anyone can VIEW the records. Such as this link to [mine](https://boardgamegeek.com/plays/bygame/user/wolfkin/subtype/boardgame/start/2017-01-01/end/2017-12-31) which show what I've played in the year 2017

Answer (score 3):

[Rankade](https://rankade.com), our multipurpose ranking system, is free to use and it's designed to manage rankings (and stats, including matchup stats, and more) for small or large groups of players.

Its algorithm (called **ree** algorithm - here's a [comparison](https://rankade.com/ree#ranking-system-comparison)) can manage - via webapp, iOS, Android - any kind of match: one-on-one, faction vs. faction (two teams, which may be asymmetrical), multiplayer, multi-faction, cooperative games, single player games, and so on.

We host many **boardgames** groups/clubs, as well as other sports/games ones (here's our [dojo](https://rankade.com/dojo)).